# Can`t remove borders from container

Tags: css, wordpress, border

How can I remove the borders inside the container:

http://lapetiteorgie.org/Clemens/wordpress/?page_id=710

I can`t find it with firebug...

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below CSS should do it:

```
media="all"
hr {
    border: none;
}
```

This will affect the `hr` element, its full CSS currently is:

```
hr {
  border: none; /* setting this to none removes the line */
  border-width: 1px 0 0;
  clear: both;
  margin: 30px 0 30px 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

If you also want to remove the border under the header, also change

```
media="all"
.navibg {
    background: url(images/whitebg.png);
    border-bottom: none;
}
```